# One's Jewish Birthday in Judaism

Tags: tefilla, blessing, pregnancy-birth

1. Is one's Jewish birthday a day of עת רצון (time of will) regarding prayer?
2. Is there a source for giving *berachos* to people on one's birthday?

Comment: the first question is a dupe of [this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52623/birthday-mazal-and-tefillah) and the second question is asked already [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/47730/blessings-on-birthdays)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [birthday, mazal and tefillah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/52623/birthday-mazal-and-tefillah)

Comment: @DonielF This question asks about the fact, the other asks about whether this fact is implied by a specific source

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer to #2 from [here](http://www.thejewishweek.com/features/first_person/birthdays_stairway_heaven) :

> When a person is born, Jewish mystics believed, the skies part to
>   enable his or her soul to come down to earth. On each birthday, the
>   skies open again, giving the celebrant one-day access to heaven for
>   his or her prayers. The birthday boy or girl should thus bless as many
>   people as possible.

If you are asking this b/c your own birthday is coming up, I'll relay what my grandpa a"h said (who lived to 93): He only wanted to live until 118, so this way he could worry about what to do when he got old.