# birthday, mazal and tefillah

Tags: tefilla, pregnancy-birth, superstition

Rav Tzadok HaKohein of writes in Divrei Chalomos (#20) the following on birthdays: 
"*On the day when a person is born, his mazal is very strong and every year on that day he does not have to fear from anything that will weaken his **mazal**.*"

Would this imply that one's *mazal* is somehow connected to *tefillah* and therefore on one's birthday, it is time of עת רצון regarding *tefillah*?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think so. I didn't see your Divrei Chalomos inside, but I don't see that he said anything about *tefillah* in your quote. I don't either see why you would think that *mazal* is connected to *tefillah*, so I don't think that this statement by Rav Tzadok would imply that there is an עת רצון on someone's birthday. (*though it doesn't necessarily imply that there is no such thing as an עת רצון on a birthday; I just don't think that there is any positive proof*)